# Find a basis for the hyperplane and use the line to extend the basis for the hyperplane to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, problem-solving

> Suppose there is a hyperplane in $\mathbb{R}^4$ that is the solution
>   set to the homogeneous equation $x+2y-3z+w=0$ and a line in
>   $\mathbb{R}^4$ given parametrically by
>   $\{t(2,-3,0,0):t\in\mathbb{R}\}$.
>
> Find a basis for the hyperplane and use the line to extend the basis for the hyperplane to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$

How could you find a basis for the hyperplane, and how would the line be useful in extending the basis for the hyperplane to a basis for $\mathbb{R}^4$?

Comment: The hyperplane will have dimension $3$ and the line will have dimension $1$. Find three vectors that span the hyperplane and add the vector that defines the line and prove that they are linearly independent.

Comment: @JohnDouma How do you find vectors which span the plane?

Comment: Plug numbers into the equation. You have four variables and you only need three vectors.

Comment: @JohnDouma How do you mean plug numbers into the equation? The equation is not vector-valued. I don't understand.

Comment: The equation is equivalent to $(1,2,-3,1)(x,y,z,w)^T=0$.

Comment: @amd The dot product of the normal vector and some point in the plane, yeah? So just pick arbitrary values for (x,y,z,w) and choose those to be my vectors? I don't see it.

Comment: Almost. You have four unknowns, but only need three vectors, so set $x$, $y$, and $z$ to three sets of arbitrary values and solve for $w$. You need to take care to make them linearly independent, which you can do by setting each variable in turn to $1$ and the other two to $0$.